# Example for MQTT in Proccesing, Sends to Broker, Nothing on Subscriber

Tags: processing, mqtt

I am trying my very first MQTT example.
And I am using Processing.

I have downloaded and installed the library using the Proccessing library tool.

In the Processing File> Examples>Contributed Libraries> MQTT is the example PublishSubscribe

I open it and run it. I get the squar box and click to make it take focus. When i type on the keyboard the visual display at shifer.io shows I am publishing messages. 
See the visual display  here: https://shiftr.io/try#processing

However the messageReceived ?callback? never seams to execute as I get no subscribed messages in the console.

I am not sure what to try next.
I am running Processing 3.3.7

Code Example:

```
import mqtt.*;

MQTTClient client;

void setup() {
  client = new MQTTClient(this);
  client.connect("mqtt://try:try@broker.shiftr.io", "processing");
  client.subscribe("/example");
  // client.unsubscribe("/example");

  size(200, 200);
  frameRate(30);
}

void draw() {}

void keyPressed() {
  client.publish("/hello", "world");
}

void messageReceived(String topic, byte[] payload) {
  println("new message: " + topic + " - " + new String(payload));
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Kevin,
Thanks for asking about code. I missed the obvious by not doing so.



import mqtt.*;

MQTTClient client;

void setup() {
  client = new MQTTClient(this);
  client.connect("mqtt://try:try@broker.shiftr.io", "processing");
  client.subscribe("/example");
  // client.unsubscribe("/example");
  
  size(200, 200);
  frameRate(30);
}

void draw() {}

void keyPressed() {
  client.publish("/hello", "world");
}

void messageReceived(String topic, byte[] payload) {
  println("new message: " + topic + " - " + new String(payload));
}

Comment: Edited question above for code example on 20180830 0733.

Comment: The library code seams to come from here: https://github.com/256dpi/processing-mqtt